# How to start my Tampermonkey script

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey

I am attempting to write a Tampermonkey script for the website https://moat.com/
In the center of the website there is an input search bar which searches brands from a database.  What I am attempting to do is figure out where that database is located.  Ideally I would be able to download it on to my hard drive and search images on my hard drive against the database.  I am not sure if this is possible.  I am fairly certain the database is saved in a JSON file somewhere but I cant find it.  The source code for the website contains many different JavaScript files and I am having difficulty reading them.  If anyone could help me find that JSON file or point me in the right direction in writing the JavaScript for the image search against the database I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: "MOAT Oracle" the database hardly is in a JSON file ...

Comment: What do you want it is impossible. The database is stored on a server (and most probably not in JSON format) and what that input text is doing is to query that (database) server for a brand name. Tampermonkey cannot help you with that.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot determine where the database is located from the frontend of a website. You can only know the address of the server which serves you the content for the page.

If you look in the Network tab of your browser's Developer Tools when you type a search query, you'll see the Ajax requests being sent to the server and how it responds to them in this address:

https://moat.com/api/autocomplete

The database is most certainly not "saved in a JSON file somewhere". The server serves responses to requests in this format because it's a good data exchange format. It's certainly not for storage of anything of the magnitude of that site.

Comment: On the network tab it is using this link https://assets.moat.com/static/webpack_bundles/moatpro.react_router.bdb54e0b9e0c1b790576.js located on line 187 of the source code.  This link itself is a minified js file.  Are you certain I cant use this link in a TM script to query the database myself using images instead of text?  Thank you for your reply.